# L5.5 - dispatch() throws an exception. How to continue the process?

Tags: php, laravel-5, queue, jobs, dispatch

I'm using **L5.5** and I wrote a simple `Controller` that runs a `dispatch()` method.

Something like this:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
  public function insertData($data) {
    // do something before
    dispatch(new SetRegionJob([$data->id]));
    // do something after
  }
}
```

Sometimes, the `dispatch()` method throws an `Exception` (I'm investigating it... but this is not the problem now) and this `Exception` stops the process and `do something after` code, is not executed.

My idea is to use `dispatch()` to run a `Job`, but if an `Exception` is thrown for `dispatch()`, the process should continue running `do something after` code.

How I can modify the code to operate as I want?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `try catch` to handle the exception, as an example:

```
try {
   dispatch(new SetRegionJob([$data->id]));
} catch (\Exception $e) {
   // do something like logging the exception
}
// do something after
```